# Trigger a stored procedure #2 within another stored procedure #1 based on input from the first stored procedure #1

Tags: json, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, insert

I need to create a stored procedure which triggers another stored procedure based on what the first stored procedure ingests.

I have a master table called 'Data_Table' which ingests JSON strings. Within the JSON string is another JSON string which is the data of a separate table.

My objective is: when the master table ingests this data, based on the 'data_set_id', it directs the JSON embedded within the table to automatically be ingested into another table via a separate stored procedure already set up. For instance:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA_TABLE_JSON (
    @JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @err int

    INSERT INTO Data_Table (
submission_id,
data_set_id,
data_string

)
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON (@JsonData, N'$') WITH (
submission_id varchar(20) N'$.submission_id',
data_set_id varchar(20) N'$.data_set_id',
data_string varchar(1000) N'$.data_string'

    )   

    SELECT @err = @@ERROR
    RETURN (@err)



END
```

I would then execute this by running the following query:

```
   DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @JsonData nvarchar(max)

SET @JsonData = N'[{"submission_id":"1","data_set_id":"1","data_string":"[{\"student_id\":1,\"full_name\":\"John Smith\",\"submission_id\":\"1\",\"data_set_id\":\"1\"}]"}]
for json path'
EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[INSERT_DATA_TABLE_JSON] @JsonData
IF @RC = 0 PRINT 'OK'
ELSE PRINT 'Error'
```

As you can see, within the 'data_string' column of the Data_Table, we have another JSON. This data_set_id =1 just means that this data is related to a specific table, in this case my Student table which has the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_STUDENTS_JSON (
    @JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @err int

    INSERT INTO Students (
student_id,
full_name,
submission_id,
data_set_id

)
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON (@JsonData, N'$') WITH (

student_id varchar(20) N'$.student_id',
full_name varchar(20) N'$.full_name',
submission_id varchar(20) N'$.submission_id',
data_set_id varchar(20) N'$.data_set_id'

    )   

    SELECT @err = @@ERROR
    RETURN (@err)



END
```

How do I automatically, allow the first stored procedure, to read the contents of the embedded JSON or otherwise, and then for it to know that it has to use that data to fill in the corresponding Students table.

Here is the JSON string just in case:

```
[{"submission_id":"1","data_set_id":"1","data_string":"[{\"student_id\":1,\"full_name\":\"John Smith\",\"submission_id\":\"1\",\"data_set_id\":\"1\"}]"}]
```

I have a second table called Lecturers which I've assigned with data_set_id = 2, so when the embedded JSON has data_set_id = 2, it directs it to the lecturers table.

Comment: Do you always have only one `"data_set_id"` in the input JSON?

Comment: @Zhorov So i've just received update that my JSON input has changed slightly but in essence the structure is now: 

LARGEJSON[ First Small JSON, Second Small JSON]

and each of the small JSONs have a "data_set_id" which are the same